# Why did Nadav and Avihu specifically not wear the Me'il?

Tags: parashat-shemini, bigdei-kehunah

The Midrash Tanchuma Acharei Mos (6) [records](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Achrei_Mot.6.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) one of the mistakes of Aharon's sons was

> וְעַל יְדֵי שֶׁנִּכְנְסוּ מְחֻסְּרֵי בְגָדִים, דִּכְתִּיב בָּהֶן
> מִיתָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וְהָיוּ עַל אַהֲרֹן וְעַל בָּנָיו בְּבֹאָם אֶל
> אֹהֶל מוֹעֵד וְגוֹ' (שם כח, מג). וּמֶה הָיוּ מְחֻסָּרִים. אָמַר רַבִּי
> לֵוִי, מְעִיל הָיוּ מְחֻסָּרִים - they entered the holy area without
> wearing the necessary clothes. What were they missing? The Me'il.

What was unique about the me'il above any other bigdei kehuna that Nadav and Avihu didn't wear it?

Answer (score 3):

The Alshich and the Kli Yakar both note that the Meil atones for speech ,namely loshon harah,and it is hinting to the idea that they spoke loshon harah on Moshe Rabbeinu and Ahron Hakohein. So in effect "they were missing the meil".

Text of the Alshich:

ומה שאמר שנכנסו בלא מעיל, אולי מתכוון למה שאמרו מתי ימותו זקנים הללו, כי המעיל כפרה על הדבור

Text of the Kli Yakar:

ולמאן דאמר מחוסרי מעיל, שהמעיל מכפר על לשון הרע, והם מדברים לשון הרע על משה ואהרן, שראויים להנהיג רק מצד זקנתם ולא מצד מעלותם, ולשון הרע נקרא גחלים וגו'